# Angular scope singleton

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, singleton, angular-promise

I have this controller:

```
class Ctrl{
  constructor($http, $scope, $stateParams){
    if(!$scope.items){
      $http.get(...).then((res)=> {
        $scope.items = res.data;
      });
    }

    if($stateParams.id){
        $scope.currItem = $scope.items[$statePrams.id];
    }
}
```

I have 2 states:

```
.state('dashboard.items', {
    url: '/items',
    templateUrl: 'items.html',
    controller:'Ctrl'
})
.state('dashboard.items.details', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: '/ItemDetails.html',
    controller: 'Ctrl'
})
```

I want to be sure that items array already initialized before I show the details of one of them.

How is it possible without code duplicating? (If else and same code inside each)

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `resolve` method in your `.state` object literal to delay instantiation of the controller https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: I tried it with resolve, but then the list page takes long time to load. I want to show the list page, load the list async, and then load the next state.

Answer (score 0):

you can use state [resolve](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) on parent level (that is exact answer on your question)

or just use service and make initialisation there. service is singleton.

Comment: I did it already. The problem is that now my list page will be loaded only after the list is initialized. I want to load the list page, and after that to load the list items. Anyway, there is a way to access parent controller from child if I will use another controller for the child?

Comment: look at the second option

Comment: There is a way in angular-ui-route to access the parent controller? (Without the scope in my case of ES6)